# Is there a way to default to "Replace in all cells" in the "Find and Replace" in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I usually want to find and replace all, but it looks like it has been set to current/highlighted cell only (https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/2131). jupyter also doesn't remember the option after the dialog goes away. Is there a way to change this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Based on all the responses given below, the answer is no.

Answer (score 43):

Select all the cells where you want to perform Find/Replace

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow key Down</kbd> or <kbd>Up</kbd>

and then,

Menu: `Edit` -> `Find and Replace`

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question

Comment: There is a better answer bellow from @J.K., no need to select all cells, you just need to click on the up and down arrow in the find and replace box.

Comment: @MickaëlLalande the answer by J.K does not OP's question. If you press the `Replace all cells` button, when the window closes, it will be defaulted to unpressed again. What OP is asking is **how to default `Replace all cells`** not how to do it. This answer does not exactly answer it as well but is closer to what the OP needs

Answer (score 39):

Press ctrl+shift+F.
Then type "find and replace".
In order to rename a variable in all cells, click on the arrow as shown in the image
[image: How to rename a variable in all cells]

Comment: If you hit `esc` to enter command mode `F` will open Find and Replace for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. If you press the `Replace all cells` button, when the window closes, it will be defaulted to unpressed again. What OP is asking is **how to default `Replace all cells`** not how to do it

Answer (score 11):

Steps
1.Go to edit -> Find and Replace -> click on it

[image]

See the highlighted option. Use this to replace  in complete notebook.

Comment: Nice - how did you generate the graphic with highlight above?

Comment: Used this approach, and the notebook froze for a few minutes, but the task was accomplished. :D

Comment: To call the find and replace dialog, you can also simply press the letter "**F**" on a cell (press escape first if you are in edit mode) .

Answer (score 3):

I just had to do it urgently so shut down the notebook kernel did it from the terminal with `sed` like this:

```
sed -i "" 's/oldword/newword/g' mynotebook.ipynb
```

That was on a mac which am using at the moment, but if you do it on ordinary linux the "" should be left out ie

```
sed -i 's/oldword/newword/g' mynotebook.ipynb
```

First time I ever needed to do such a thing in years but if it happened more often would be good if it could be done from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First select all the cells (Esc->Ctrl+Shift+arrow_down_key).
Then Edit-> Find and Replace.

If only in one cell, then use the shortcut 'F' key.

Answer (score 0):

Just do ctr+a outside the cell thats all:-
It will select all the cells and perform find and replace

[image]