# How to "find and replace" text?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I see there is such command in the `Edit` menu tab, but is dim grey, both if I am inside a code tab and if I am outside it, as you can see in the attached screenshot.
How can I perform such operation?
[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UPDATE:

with the latest version of Jupyter lab (>1.1.4) this function is added!

Just click "Find", below the "Edit" menu: a contextual window will appear at the top right of the notebook.

There you click on the small arrow at the left side of the text field, and the "replace" function appear.

OLD ANSWER (still good anyway):

At the end, I found this solution, but it's only for those who know how to use VIM, the text editor.

I installed an extension, [jupyterlab-vim](https://github.com/jwkvam/jupyterlab-vim), and so I can use VIM commands for search and replace text.

This appears to be an overkill as solution, but for VIM lovers (like me) using many VIM commands in Jupyter Lab is just fabulous.

Answer (score 1):

A solution will be to:
`sed -i "" 's/oldword/newword/g' mynotebook.ipynb`

Found here: [Is there a way to default to "Replace in all cells" in the "Find and Replace" in jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217668/is-there-a-way-to-default-to-replace-in-all-cells-in-the-find-and-replace-in)

Answer (score 1):

the shortcut for replacing all values in a cell is
`Shift + Ctrl + H : Find and Replace all in current cell`

You can access and set your own shortcuts via keyboard preferences or by `Ctrl + M + H`